# Android after clicking picture white screen appears and then app gets crashed

Tags: android

I open camera from my android app it successfully takes the picture then after that white screen appears in the app and then app gets crashed, giving E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1 this as error. can somebody please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please share exact error picture and provide code as well

Comment: are you trying to save into external storage after taking the picture? if so, you will need to request for the right permission

Comment: No I just need to show this on screen, then the image  is uploaded on servers

Comment: @KaranMehta this is the only errorI am getting

Answer (score 0):

In my Case i tried below code..

In your `Activity.xml` layout file add below code..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/photo"/>

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

After that write below code in your `CameraActivtiy` class..

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity{   
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;
private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } 
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
    {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}}
```

In your `AndroidManifest` file write below code..

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For open camera**

```
 Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                    photoFile);
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

**On ActivityResult**

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {

                // fileSize = getFileSizeInKB(photoFile);
                photoFile = saveBitmapToFile(photoFile);



                if (photoFile != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(photoFile.getName())) {
                   //photo is found do code here
                }



            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.something_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}
```

And

```
public File saveBitmapToFile(File file) {
        try {

            // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            o.inSampleSize = 6;
            // factor of downsizing the image

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
            inputStream.close();

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                    o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            orientedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
            inputStream.close();

            // here i override the original image file
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            orientedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```